# Sharing data with services but ng-model still not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to share data between main.html (my main view) and header.html (the embedded template on page). I am having two issues with this approach:

1. Data does not show on the dropdown in `header.html`, unless I do ....
2. Doing 1) creates another scope, so the changes are not perpetuated across the application until the next refresh.

All my data is kept in a service, and I want it to update in real-time whenever a user changes an option in the dropdown. I am using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) to store the data in the browser cache.

index.html

```
  <div ng-include="'views/templates/header.html'"></div>
  <!-- main.html goes in view -->    
  <div ng-view=""></div>
```

header.html

```
<header class="header-style-2">
   <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="vm.selectedCurrency" ng-options="o as o for o in vm.currencyList" ng-change="vm.setCurrency(vm.selectedCurrency)"></select>
</header>
```

main.html

```
<div class="details-sec"><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a> <span class="font-montserrat">{{ product.price }} {{ vm.selectedCurrency }}</span> </div>
```

main.js - MainController

```
vm.currencyList = MainService.getCurrencyList();
vm.selectedCurrency = MainService.getCurrency();

vm.setCurrency = function(selectedCurrency) {
  vm.selectedCurrency = MainService.setCurrency(selectedCurrency);
};
```

main.js - MainService

```
function getCurrencyList()
{
  var currencyList = ['GBP', 'USD', 'EUR'];
  return currencyList;
}

function getCurrency() {
  if($localStorage.selectedCurrency) {
    return $localStorage.selectedCurrency;
  }
  return getCurrencyList()[0];
}

function setCurrency(newSelectedCurrency) {
  $localStorage.selectedCurrency = newSelectedCurrency;      
}

function resetCurrency() {
  $localStorage.selectedCurrency = getCurrencyList()[0];      
}
```

Comment: I see that header.html is out of view so I quess out of controller's scope. You should insert header into main.html or use another controller/directive for header with [shared factorry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: `vm.selectedCurrency = MainService.setCurrency(selectedCurrency);` is wrong, should be `MainService.setCurrency(selectedCurrency);` only.